# Android - when to call REST API when starting new activity

Tags: android, rest, android-activity

I have `Activity` `A` and `Activity` `B`.

`A` has a button that opens `B`.

Activity `B` has to display some info from API that I call.

The problem: When I open the activity, there is a moment when the data is empty (I am waiting for a response from the API), since I am calling the API inside `onViewCreated` method. If on the other hand I would call the API inside Activity `A`, I would have to wait for a response to be able to open Activity `B`. My question is what are the best practices for when to call the API that needs to display data as soon as the new activity starts

Comment: Either wait on A or B; no other choice. Data fetching takes some time and you have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches can be done, either way you will have to wait at some instance

1. you could call the api in the first activity and then pass the data as 
   `extra` to the next activity
2. You could call the api in second activity directly, so while calling the api in background thread you could show some progress dialog

Answer (score 1):

Pretty common use case... 
Data fetching takes time and in these couple of seconds (for poor 3G / WIFI) the UI seems empty.
Possible solutions are:

- Use a ProgressBar before the API call and dismiss it when the call completes.
- Use an Loading State UI until the data is fetched, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well You can call the api and make sure to start a progress dialog when calling the api and hide the progress dialog after the response obtained. this way user will wait till the response is processed

Answer (score 0):

**Add Progress Dialog**, while calling API,normally server will take some time to give Data.
Hide the Progress dialog in onResponse and onError Response .Do Api call before populating your view  to user.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your API in **onCreate()** or in **onResume()** method of the activity. It is a good practice to call the API in the Activity which required API data. But sometimes it depends on the situations.

Use a **ProgressBar** before calling the API and **dismiss** it after getting the data from API.

Answer (score 0):

Call the Api in **onResume()** of the **Activity B** and also make sure to add a progressDialog and hide it on the response.